# Django - Items not showing up in Products page

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to create a basic e-commerce site in Django. I have created a products page and when I open the page, my products are not showing up. I'm new to Django and have no idea what to do.

urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index),
        path('products', views.products)
    ]
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from products.models import Product
    
    
    def index(request):
        products = Product.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'products': products})
    
    def products(request):
        return render(request, 'products.html')
```

index.html file in templates folder

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}PyShop</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">PyShop</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/products">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                           data-toggle="dropdown"
                           aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>
    
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

products.html file in the same templates folder

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    
    {% block content %}
        <h1 class="my-2">Products</h1>
        <div class="row">
        {%for p in products%}
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="{{Product.image_url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{Product.name}}">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{Product.name}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">${{Product.price}}</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}
    </div>
    {% endblock content %}
```

I also debugged the NameError for my Product model. Now the products are not showing up.
I had encountered this problem in another project as well. Not knowing what to do, I created that project from scratch once more. The problem still continues.

Comment: Just from a quick observation, shouldn't you be using `p.name` instead of `Product.name` in `base.html`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your are confusing !
do the following instruction :

1-remove this code

```
def products(request):
    return render(request, 'products.html')
```

2- in products.html remove

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

add this code :

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
```

Comment: try with simple example ! then do it on your case

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake in for loop check the

```
products = Product.objects.all()
return render(request, 'index.html', {'products': products}) #products is send to index.html and the the for loop syntax is for name_of_params in para
```

Your for loop is wrong.

Yours:  `{%for p in products%}`

Solution: `{%for product in p %}`